Mereological nihilism without simples?
Is it possible to maintain mereological nihilism without simples? It seems to me that, despite the parsimony and elegance of this mereology, in the end one is forced to assume something like ultimate elements without irreducible parts. That sounds a bit naïve to me.
Would there be any way to sustain mereological nihilism that divides parts and composites 'all the way down'?
I imagine the problem with this is that, in the end, apparent wholes dissolve and there’s no way to causally explain anything without a set of irreducible simples...

Does 'simples' mean ontological primitives?

@JD A "simple" is usually understood to be an object without proper parts.

@JD Good question, I don't see how they can't be...

If you are dividing into parts "all the way down" then how is it mereological nihilism? Mereological nihilism means no parts, only "simples arranged tablewise". If there are no simples and no parts, so no composites, what is left? Outright existence nihilism?

@Conifold I guess so. At least that seems less naïve to me.

@Conifold Why does arranged simples not imply the existence of simples + arrangement as irreducible things with respect to one another?

Because arranging is a human exercise, not part of the ontology. That we choose to slap labels on some arrangements of interest to us does not turn them into objectively existing things.

@Conifold So, mereological nihilism must be different from Zimmerman's "atomless gunk", with wholes whose parts all have further proper parts infinitely (= gunk), right?
(Cf. Dean W. (1996). "Could Extended Objects Be Made Out of Simple Parts? An Argument for "Atomless Gunk"". Philosophy and Phenomenological Research. 56 (1): 1–29.)

Aristotle was a classical proponent of potential infinite divisibility and non-existence of atoms, but he surely did not deny existence of parts. The definition of gunk is that  all of its parts have proper parts. Sider even argued that the possibility of gunk rules out van Inwagen's mereological nihilism altogether, see his Van Inwagen and the Possibility of Gunk.

@Conifold Thank you for your precise answers. The contradiction is that mereological nihilism excludes gunk because it cannot talk about parts, while the latter needs to talk about parts. But it would be enough for the nihilist to say that 'entities with proper parts do not exist,' and for the gunk theorist to say that 'Each part of an object, including itself, has proper parts.' Ultimately, this implies that nothing exists.
It took me a while to respond because I was pondering this. But the comment box is telling me not to drag out the topic any further and to use a chat instead

@user509184 You say "A "simple" is usually understood to be an object without proper parts." I'm okay with simple being elemental in the sense it's non-compositional. My question is a little more specific. Are simples taken to be ontological primitives of a sort. As I understand it, in mereological nihilism, macroworld entities are simply reduced to configurations of particles. Thus, particles are simples, but are they in some metaphysical sense excluded from being ontological? That is to say, do simples find metaphysical grounding in the traditional notions of ontological commitment?

@JD I don't know what you mean when you ask if simples are "in some metaphysical sense excluded from being ontological". I would not say that any actually-existing physical object is metaphysically grounded in any notion of ontological commitment at all. Finally, about primitives: if you mean by "primitives" anything like what I imagine, then no, I do not think simples are primitives. Think of building up a language for describing the world from sense-data, like Carnap's project in the Aufbau. You never directly observe an electron. Instead you infer its existence from experiment and models.

@JD Think of what the Ramsey sentence for an electron would be, in such a language. It would be truly vast, unreasonable to write out in its entirety. So an electron is very far from being a primitive in this language. My point is that a simple is not necessarily a primitive in any system you might use for reasoning about the world. Since simples generally cannot be directly observed and their existence must be inferred indirectly, in any language or system for reasoning in which primitives are given by sense-data (Russell) or observations (Quine), simples won't be primitives.

A simple is usually taken to be an object with no proper parts. Let's be careful about this:
Definition 1. y is simple if there does not exist x such that x is a proper part of y.
Mereological nihilism is usually taken to be the position that no objects have proper parts. Let's try to make this precise:
Definition 2. Mereological nihilism is the claim that there do not exist objects x,y such that x is a proper part of y.
With this in mind, it is straightforward to prove (in classical logic) that:
Theorem 3. The following are equivalent:

Mereological nihilism is true, and there exist no simple objects.

No objects exist.


So indeed, you can have mereological nihilism and nonexistence of simples. You just have to accept that nothing exists. Perhaps that is a bit more "parsimony and elegance" than you wanted!
Here is a variation on that idea. Sometimes when people talk about mereological nihilism, they are not really thinking about the dictionary definition that you would find on SEP and which I stated above as Definition 2. Instead, sometimes people are thinking about composition principles, i.e., principles that assert that, given some collection of objects, there exists a single object (the composite of the collection) whose parts are precisely those objects in the given collection, and their subparts.
The most liberal composition principle asserts that every collection of objects has a composite. Some people object to such composition principles, e.g. on the grounds that intuitively there is no single object whose proper parts are precisely the head of Napoleon, my bank account balance, and all the helium in the universe (and their subparts).
Such people generally take the position that a collection of objects must satisfy some kind of condition in order to have a composite. There is some difficulty in saying precisely what this condition ought to be. In response to this difficulty, sometimes people take the position that there is in fact no reliable composition principle at all, i.e., there is no natural condition on a collection of objects which ensures that the collection has a composite.
As far as I can tell, this train of thought is one common entree into mereological nihilism. Let us call this stance "weak mereological nihilism," i.e.,
Definition 4. Weak mereological nihilism is the claim that there does not exist a nontrivial natural property P of collections of objects such that, if S has property P, then S has a composite.
This is not really a well-defined notion, at least not yet: I have not given an account of what a natural property is, and I won't try to do that here, but in the wake of Lewis's paper "Putnam's paradox" (1984) there have been various attempts in the literature to make sense of "naturality" of properties, e.g. in Williams "Eligibility and inscrutability" (2007), and some approaches have been pretty good, so it seems like it is not a hopeless task.
Weak mereological nihilism does not entail mereological nihilism. Under weak mereological nihilism, objects can have proper parts. Collections of objects can have composites. Those composites just don't have their existence guaranteed by any kind of discernible principle. The most obvious way that this is possible is if all facts about proper parthood are brute facts.
Finally, here is an answer of the kind that I imagine you were hoping for. Suppose that all facts about proper parthood are brute facts. Suppose also that every object has a proper part, i.e., there are no atoms, every thing is composed of smaller stuff. Then you have weak mereological nihilism (but not mereological nihilism!), and you have no simples.
To be clear: to me, this is all just an interesting intellectual exercise. I think there are convincing Moorean arguments ("Here is a hand...") for the existence of nontrivial composition principles in the actual world around us, so that neither mereological nihilism nor weak mereological nihilism actually hold.

I'm interested in the relationship between D1 and D2. I want to know if I've understood you correctly:
D1 says that a simple is indivisible because it is the absence of proper parts;
D2 says that there are no objects composed of parts. So the absence of proper parts (D1) co-implies the negation of all wholes with proper parts.
Have I understood you correctly?

@Ian Basically yes, but I would be careful about the wording. D1 says that a simple does not have proper parts. (It does not say that a simple is an absence.) D2 says that objects do not have proper parts. (It does not speak of composition, which could perhaps confuse the issue, since D2 makes sense without any idea of composition principles at all.)

Perfect. This answer is absolutely splendid. I think I know why you mention Moore, but it seems to me that mereological nihilism can respond to that objection. But that is another matter!

@Ian About your third sentence: the nonexistence of proper parts implies the nonexistence of objects with proper parts. I don't know what "co-implies" means. Also, it is nonexistence, rather than negation, which is implied, because I think that it is only propositions which have negations, and objects in general do not have negations. Finally I did not use the term "wholes" in what I wrote, and I would want to define it carefully if I were going to use it--is a "whole" an object with proper parts, or is it a composite produced by a composition principle, or is it any object whatsoever, etc.

@Ian Thanks, glad you're happy with the answer.

Thank you again. Do you know any literature to delve deeper into this? I'm very interested in this topic but I come from continental phil. and sometimes It's hard for me to grap the language being used.

@Ian About mereology, I don't know any single reference which is a better starting point than the SEP article on mereology. Goodman and Quine is pretty good too. But to me it makes sense to start with the SEP article and start looking up references from there which go further into the ideas you want to read more about.

Ok, I will study the SEP entry carefully then. Many thanks!
